# How to get an absolute URL with the slugify filter in Eleventy Liquid templates?

Tags: liquid, eleventy

In an Eleventy site using Liquid templates I can usually get a full/absolute URL with the `url` filter like this `{{'/books/' | url}}`

When I am looping through data I need to use the `slugify` filter to convert that data into a usable URL like this: `/books/{{book.title | slugify}}`

That works, but I get a URL that is not absolute.  How can I get both to happen?  I have tried the following:

- `{{'/books/' {% book.title | slugify %} | url}}`
- `{{'/books/' {{ book.title | slugify }} | url}}`
- `{{'/books/'book.title | slugify | url}}`

I can't seem to find any documentation on using multiple filters like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ '/books/' | url }}{{ book.title | slugify | url }}

<a href="{{ '/books/' | url }}{{ book.title | slugify | url }}">{{ book.title }}</a>
```

Comment: ok, simple enough, thanks! I guess I was trying to first get the slug and then process the whole string as a URL. This make a lot of sense, thanks!